# Math Functions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have a generated a set of random values which I expect to fit in Beta Distribution.

Is there any library which provides function to calculate betafit or uniformfit Just like it is available in Matlab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. I also got this

http://www.meta-numerics.net/Documentation/html/8ff81058-d821-cfa0-eccf-b0c21d66a0a3.htm

Meta.Numerics also contains some classes which solves my problem.

There is a static function FitToSample() in each distribution. It calculates the parameters of the distribution.

For example, BetaDistribution.FitToSample() calculates me the alpha and beta values for the input data.

But how to check whether the data actually fits the beta distribution ?

If anyone of you have used this, can you please tell me how to verify whether the input data fits the distribution( ex : exponential, beta).

Comment: This sounds like a new question to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Stats Master](http://www.dewresearch.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=156%3astats-master-statistical-add-on-package-for-mtxvec&catid=54%3aproducts&Itemid=79) by Dew Research.

[BetaFit](http://www.dewresearch.com/help/vsnet/statsmaster/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=%21%21OVERLOADED_BetaFit_Dew_Stats_Statistics.html)
[UniformFit](http://www.dewresearch.com/help/vsnet/statsmaster/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=!!OVERLOADED_UniformFit_Dew_Stats_Statistics.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about these functions, but looks like dewresearch got them. Used their software before, but it's not free (only the trial)

http://www.dewresearch.com/help/vsnet/statsmaster/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=Dew_Stats_Statistics_BetaFit@TVec@TSample@TSample@Integer@TSample.html

Comment: Registration in DEW Stats gives a broken link